# For Android development, some questions about Java SDK and 32/64 bit versions

Tags: java, android

I am about to get my feet wet in Android development, and I had some questions about the Java SDK as it pertains to Android coding.

I'm running Win 7 x64 - is it better if I run the 32-bit JDK, or the 64 bit JDK?  I've done some searching, and keep finding conflicting answers.

Also, if I'm about to install the SDK, should I uninstall the Java Run Time on my machine first?  Does the SDK serve the same purpose?  Or do I need both installed at the same time?

Thanks!  And I'm sorry if you guys have heard these questions before.  (I did try to look up the info first, I promise!)  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install both the 32-bit and 64-bit JDKs. Without the 32-bit JDK, the Android plugin for Eclipse won't install. You don't need to uninstall any existing JREs.

EDIT: This answer applies only to Eclipse with the Android plugin, which is no longer a supported way of developing for Android. For Android Studio, if you have a 64-bit Windows OS, I believe you only need the 64-bit version of Java. (Since everything constantly changes, this edit will eventually join my original answer in being out of date. Consult the latest system requirement docs, currently at the bottom of the [Android Studio download page here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).)

Comment: You don't need to have the 64bit JDK though, right? (I mean unless you need it for something else)

Comment: @poke - probably not, but then you'd have to install the 32-bit version of Eclipse. I think that would be a waste on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Oh, that's true, never really thought about that. But do 32bit plugins work with 64bit Eclipse? Or is there actually not a difference for plugins, but just for the Android SDK?

Comment: That's a very good question, about the plugins.  For the sake of Android development in general, does it matter whether you use 32 or 64 bit JDK?

Comment: I'm doing Android development using the 64-bit version of Eclipse. The Android tools required 32-bit Java. I don't know whether that makes the tools "32 bit plugins", but it all works.

Comment: @Stephen - You can do everything with the 32-bit JDK, I think, although you probably need to use the 32-bit Eclipse. However, you can't get things working with only the 64-bit JDK and 64-bit Eclipse; you need the 32-bit JDK as well.

Comment: @Tedd - Is there any benefit to using 64-bit versions of either JDK or Eclipse then?

Comment: @Stephen - I think that 64-bit versions of Eclipse will run better in a 64-bit Windows environment. I have no basis for saying this; it's just a guess on my part, but it seems reasonable. I don't know that there are any other benefit.